# Is it possible to version control Azure Devops (VSTS) deployment configuration?

Tags: .net, azure, tfs, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I have inherited a legacy application with fairly complicated deployment, both in terms of the number of stages (40+) and the scripts that are run. We constantly have deployment failures which can mostly be solved by changing something in the deployment scripts.

One of the problems with this is I never know if something was changed in the deployment properties or if some other thing has broken the deployment script itself.

So, is there any way to version control  Azure Devops (VSTS) deployment configuration, [the way you could with, say Jenkins](https://www.coveros.com/version-control-your-jenkins-server-configuration-with-git/)?

Comment: Do you use VSTS build or release to deploy project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use VSTS build to deploy project, you could consider [using YAML builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/build-yaml?view=vsts). In a YAML build definition, your CI build process configured as code, which means:

- The definition is versioned with your code and follows the same
  branching structure as your code. So you get validation of your
  changes through code reviews in pull requests and branch build
  policies.
- If a change to the build process causes a break or results in an
  unexpected outcome, you can much more easily identify the issue
  because the change is in version control with the rest of your
  codebase. This way you can more clearly see the issue and fix it like
  any other kind of bug.

If you use VSTS release, you can only compare release definitions from the **History** tab. If you use **Inline Script** in release definitions, you can see the difference when you compare the then. If you use script file, then you can not see the difference from History tab.